# How to share behavior between different custom controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I have two custom controls: `CustomTextBox` and `CustomNumericUpDown`. I want them to have a shared behavior, which consists of a few methods and a few properties.

Solutions I came up with:

1. **Both should extend an abstract class containing the shared behavior.** The problem is that one extends `TextBox` the other extends `NumericUpDown`. I cannot think of a way for both of them to inherit my abstract class except by multiple inheritance, which is not allowed in C#.
2. **Implement a shared interface.** This is obviously stupid since interfaces cannot have an implementation.
3. **Using extension methods**. More specifically, make both of them share an interface, and create extension methods for this interface. The problem is that [you cannot (currently) have extension properties in C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/10/05/why-no-extension-properties/), and I really do not want to implement getters and setters using actual methods due to [the principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Is there an elegant approach to this problem that doesn't involve repeating code?

---

**Edit**:

---

For example, I want both `CustomTextBox` and `CustomNumericUpDown` to have a `ValidateInput()` method and a `ValidationRules` property. i.e., I want to add a method and a property to both of them.

Comment: Sounds like you're describing [traits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_programming)). Support for _default interface methods_ has been [proposed](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/default-interface-methods.md) for a future version of C#

Comment: Is your "shared behavior" going to need to rely on specifics of individual derived controls, or only on the common base Control class?

Comment: @lesscode, it will rely on the specifics of individual derived controls...

Comment: In that case I'm not sure you're going to find a particularly elegant solution. A combination of interfaces and [delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) would probably be a start, but if the delegate needs to switch on the type of the original receiver you're just pushing the mess elsewhere.

Comment: @lesscode - so copying the code is a legit solution?

Comment: No, I wouldn't say that's _ever_ a legit way to go.

Comment: @lesscode - So what *should* I do? If you have a solution in mind, could you please elaborate in an answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161401/discussion-between-lesscode-and-sipo).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my thought,

Create class with common functions of both controls,

Inject it to both control initialization, you can access common functions form common class

```
public class CommonFunctions
{
    public void ValidateInput(Object sender){
        // do your validation logic
    }
}

public class CustomTextBox : TextBox 
{
    private CommonFunctions _commonFunctions;

    public CustomTextBox(CommonFunctions commonFunctions)
    {
            _commonFunctions = commonFunctions;
    }

    private void Control_TextChanged(Object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
              _commonFunctions.ValidateInput(sender);
    }

}

public class CustomNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown 
{
    private CommonFunctions _commonFunctions;

    public CustomNumericUpDown(CommonFunctions commonFunctions)
    {
            _commonFunctions = commonFunctions;
    }

    private void Control_TextChanged(Object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
              _commonFunctions.ValidateInput(sender);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me! Using your solution, how to address the issue of common properties?

Comment: `TextBox` and `NumericUpDown` have different properties, you can not combine it, could you please add which properties you need to concern

Answer (score 1):

Far from elegant, but if you don't need to rely on the specific implementation details of the derived controls, you could use a combination of an interface (to enforce the implementation of the properties and methods you want), and [delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) (to encapsulate/centralize the shared behavior).

The implementation of the interface in the derived controls is completely boilerplate and always delegates elsewhere.

```
public class ValidationService
{
    public void RegisterRules(Control control, string[] rules)
    {
        // store rules
    }

    public string[] GetRules(Control control)
    {
        // retrieve rules
    }

    public void Validate(Control control)
    {
        // validate
    }
}

public interface IValidatable
{
    ValidationService ValidationService { get; set; }
    string[] Rules { get; set; }
    void ValidateControl();
}

public class MyTextBox : TextBox, IValidatable
{
    public ValidationService ValidationService { get; set; }

    public string[] Rules
    {
        get => ValidationService.GetRules(this);
        set => ValidationService.RegisterRules(this, value);
    }

    public void ValidateControl()
    {
        ValidationService.Validate(this);
    }
}

public class MyNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown, IValidatable
{
    public ValidationService ValidationService { get; set; }

    public string[] Rules
    {
        get => ValidationService.GetRules(this);
        set => ValidationService.RegisterRules(this, value);
    }

    public void ValidateControl()
    {
        ValidationService.Validate(this);
    }
}
```

This approach gets messy, however, if your validation behavior relies on specific details of the derived controls.

Answer (score 0):

create a base class containing the common functionality. extend that class for each of the controls you need and place the control inside that class.

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl 
{
   public MyUserControl() : base() 
   {
   }
   // add common behaviour here (validation, etc)
}

public class MyTextBox : MyUserControl 
{
   public MyTextBox() : base() 
   {
      Add(new TextBox());
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me! I am not sure I understand your solution. Where did the `Add` method come from and what is its purpose?

Comment: Add is from UserControl... read a bit about user controls: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I know what are `UserControl`s, but as far as I know, they don't have an `Add()` method...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: AddChild(), not Add()